# Google Play Services for Froyo, adSize and adUnitId not found

Tags: java, android, google-play-services

I have a problem with Google Play Services for Froyo.
If I use Google Play Services (not Froyo) all work great.
If I use the one for Froyo, I have several errors, for example:

> The import `com.google.android.gms.ads` cannot be resolved" in Java and
>
> No resource identifier found for attribute '`adSize`'in package...
>   No resource identifier found for attribute '`adUnitId`' in package...

... in the console.
I add the library in Java build path and in the *Properties* -> *Android* but it is still not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because AdMob is not supported on Froyo Google Play Services.

The [Admob Guide](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/android/quick-start) states the following prerequisites:

- Running Android Studio 0.8 or higher
- Developing for **Android level 9** or higher

Froyo is API level 8, so it is not supported.

I think you will have to use to old AdMob Ads SDK when working with Google Play Services for Froyo - see [this document](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/android/play-migration).